# split malloc mem space

Tags: c++, split, malloc

I am using MS VS 2010, C++, unmanaged. I would like to split allocated area if possible. For example let's say I allocated a 1KB space in memory:

```
void* space = malloc(1024);
```

later, I decided to have this block as seperate 512B and 512B spaces:

```
space1 = 512B and space2 = 512B
```

and finally when I want to get rid of these spaces I wanna free them seperately:

```
free(space1);
free(space2);
```

is this possible without reallocation/expanding/shrinking memory?

Thank you all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't free them separately, as malloc() will keep only one copy of the necessary bookkeeping data, so it can only free one chunk. You would have to write your own malloc/free wrappers.

Comment: That was quick :) I wished there was a solution for this.. Well this would wait until ;I start to write memory manager than.. thnx.

Comment: @MCA, it is customary to accept the answer you prefer using the check mark that is beneath the number of votes it has received.  As DeadMg's answer appears to be the one you've decided meets your immediate needs, you should accept it.

Comment: oh, sorry.. I am kinda new in this web site.. I didn't notice I should select an answer..

Comment: @MCA: Why does everybody and their brother want to re-write the memory manager. It has taken nearly 40 years to get to the state it is currently in (and is very efficient). You can't do better (unless you have a team of PhD candidates and forty years) so don't try.

Comment: Cause windows api is not doing what I wanna do. I could have split allocated memory. I actually kinda need more performance, so I allocate memory once with Virtual Alloc and use it in my own way. In this way I can manage efficiently xbox memory and pc memory.

Comment: @MCA: You won't do a better job than using malloc() and free(), really.

Answer (score 1):

In short: You'll have to write your own memory allocator on top of malloc/new.

The longer version:
Since memory allocator implementations differ, there's no way to portably modify their internal data structures that keep track of allocated and free blocks & their boundaries.

For example, there are techniques that prepend a short amount of data to each memory block. You couldn't split such a block because the additional bookkeeping data would expand the size of the block.

Other techniques place their management data externally from the blocks, such as by bitmaps, linked lists and so on. You may have more luck with them.

Again, you'll be better of to write your own allocator.

Even better, if at all possible, try to find alternative means to manage your memory. Maybe pool allocators are more something you need.

Comment: +1 pool would work well for equal-sized blocks or collections of objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows APIs for heaps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366711(VS.85).aspx

`HeapAlloc()` is the equivalent of `malloc`. The main difference is that is receives another parameter: which heap to use. These heaps can be created with `HeapCreate`, and you can reserve space for them.